# How can I move this icon?

Tags: swiftui

I want to get this plus icon to be flush up with the text.

[image: picture of initial problem]

Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("FamilyBite")
                    .font(Font.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(Font.Weight.black)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding()
            }
            Button(action: signIn) {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: 10.0, height: 10.0, alignment: .leadingFirstTextBaseline)
                    .padding()
                Text("Create a delivery")
                    .frame(minWidth:0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 20, maxHeight: 70, alignment: .center)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 20))
                    .fontWeight(Font.Weight.semibold)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 0, y: 2)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

I made a quick mockup of what I tried to replicate.

[image: picture of mockup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to make looks like a [`Label`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/label):

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Label {
        Text("Create a delivery")
            .font(Font.system(size: 20))
            .fontWeight(Font.Weight.semibold)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
    } icon: {
        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
    }
    .frame(height: 70)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        
}
```

The "FamilyBite" text looks like a navigation title. Consider using a `NavigationStack`:

```
NavigationStack {
    VStack {
        // the button and spacer go here...
    }
    .navigationTitle("FamilyBite")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to shrink it down so the left and right side don't touch the borders of the screen, and if yes how?

Comment: @NotPaperMario851 That's not what your mockup showed, but okay, just add `.padding()` to the button *after* the shadow.

Comment: Sorry, for the misconception of the mockup, but massive thanks for help!